# Calculate total hours worked

Tags: php

I have an array which contains the days and the in/out of the employers during the day. Usually it's only 4 rows per day `(In -> Out (lunch) -> In -> Out)`

I would like to SUM all hours worked according to the in/out and show it to the employer.

So my array of days is structured this way:

```
Day '2016-07-01' -> Events (4) -> (0) => ('in', '09:00')
                                  (1) => ('out', '13:00')
                                  (2) => ('in', '14:00')
                                  (3) => ('out', '17:00')
```

And so on..

To the example above the code below is printing `6.90` which is incorrect, the right result should be 8 hours.

```
$total_minutes = 0;
$total_hours   = 0;

foreach($listOfDays as $day)
{
   foreach($day->events as $key => $event)
   {
      // It's always 'in'
      if(($key % 2 == 0) || $key == 0)
      {
         $hour_in  = new DateTime($event->hour);
         $hour_out = null;

         if(isset($day->events[$key + 1]->hour))
           $hour_out = new DateTime($day->events[$key + 1]->hour);

         if($hour_out != null)
         {
            $total_hours += $hour_out->diff($hour_in)->format('%H');
            $total_minutes += $hour_out->diff($hour_in)->format('%i');
         } 
      }
      // It's always 'out'
      else
      {
        $hour_in  = new DateTime($day->events[$key - 1]->hour);
        $hour_out = new DateTime($event->hour);

        $total_hours += $hour_out->diff($hour_in)->format('%H');
        $total_minutes += $hour_out->diff($hour_in)->format('%i');
      }
   }
}

$total_hours_worked = $total_hours . '.' . $total_minutes;
print_r($total_hours_worked);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**.

Since the `key % 2` is always the `out` movement, I don't need the condition for the `in` movement, because the `out` already validates.

```
if($key % 2 != 0)
{
    $hour_in  = null;
    $hour_out = $event->hour;

    if(isset($day->events[$key - 1]->hour))
        $hour_in = $day->events[$key - 1]->hour;

    if($hour_in != null)
        $diff += (strtotime($hour_out) - strtotime($hour_in));
}
```

In the end of the loop:

```
$total              = $diff / 60;
$total_hours        = floor($total / 60);
$total_minutes      = floor($total % 60);
$total_hours_worked = sprintf('%02dh%02d', $total_hours, $total_minutes);
```

Based on [PHP Calculate total time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13835816/php-calculate-total-time)

Answer (score 0):

For Calculate the time frame between two times you can check with below code

```
function calculateTotalTime($fromtime_temp, $totime_temp){
    $fromtime = $fromtime_temp;
    $totime = $totime_temp;

    $totalSec = (strtotime($totime) - strtotime($fromtime));
    $totalMin = floor($totalSec/60);
    $totalSec = $totalSec%60;

    $totalHour = floor($totalMin/60);
    $totalMin = $totalMin%60;

    $totalDay = floor($totalHour/24);
    $totalHour = $totalHour%24;


    $totalMonth = floor($totalDay/30);
    $totalDay = $totalDay%30;

    $totalWeek = floor($totalDay/7);
    $totalDay = $totalDay%7;

    $totalYear = floor($totalMonth/12);
    $totalMonth = $totalMonth%12;


    $returnValue = "";
    if($totalYear > 0){
        if ($totalYear == 1) {
            $returnValue .= $totalYear.'year '; 
        }else{
            $returnValue .= $totalYear.'years ';
        }
    }

    if ( $totalMonth > 0 ) {
        if ($totalMonth == 1) {
            $returnValue .= $totalMonth.'month ';   
        }else{
            $returnValue .= $totalMonth.'months ';
        }
    }

    if ( $totalWeek > 0 ) {
        if ($totalWeek == 1) {
            $returnValue .= $totalWeek.'week '; 
        }else{
            $returnValue .= $totalWeek.'weeks ';
        }
    }

    if ( $totalDay > 0 ) {
        if ($totalDay == 1) {
            $returnValue .= $totalDay.'day ';   
        }else{
            $returnValue .= $totalDay.'days ';
        }
    }

    if ( $totalHour > 0 ) {
        if ($totalHour == 1) {
            $returnValue .= $totalHour.'hour '; 
        }else{
            $returnValue .= $totalHour.'hours ';
        }
    }

    if ( $totalMin > 0 ) {
        if ($totalMin == 1) {
            $returnValue .= $totalMin.'min ';   
        }else{
            $returnValue .= $totalMin.'mins ';
        }
    }

    if ( $totalSec > 0 ) {
        if ($totalSec == 1) {
            $returnValue .= $totalSec.'sec ';   
        }else{
            $returnValue .= $totalSec.'secs ';
        }
    }

    return $returnValue;
}
```

It will return the proper formatted string value to direct display on client site and also you can change the format